# FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT only happens on Android w/ Firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, webgl, framebuffer

I have some javascript/webgl code that works on every browser I've tried, except for the mobile version of firefox running on Android. The problem has something to do with being "[framebuffer complete](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Completeness)", but I don't know what specifically is wrong.

Here's the smallest repro I could make. It's supposed to just create a texture and a framebuffer, set some properties, then check that the framebuffer is 'complete':

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
var GL = WebGLRenderingContext;
if (gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float') === null) {
    alert("No float support.");
}

var texture = gl.createTexture();
var frameBuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);

gl.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texImage2D(
    GL.TEXTURE_2D, //target
    0,             //level
    GL.RGBA,       //internalformat
    2,             //width
    2,             //height
    0,             //border
    GL.RGBA,       //format
    GL.FLOAT,      // type [changing to UNSIGNED_BYTE "fixes" the failure...?]
    null           // pixels
);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(
    GL.FRAMEBUFFER,
    GL.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    GL.TEXTURE_2D,
    texture,
    0);

var result = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(GL.FRAMEBUFFER);
if (result === GL.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    alert("success (FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)");
} else {
    alert("ERROR " + ({
        [0]: "Argument wasn't a frame buffer",
        [GL.INVALID_ENUM]: "INVALID_ENUM",
        [GL.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT]: "FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT",
        [GL.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT]:
            "FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT",
        [GL.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS]: "FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS",
        [GL.FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED]: "FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED"
    }[result] || result));
}
```

In my testing, this code succeeds on Windows+Firefox-44, Windows+Chrome-49, Android+Chrome, and Ubuntu+Firefox. But it fails with `FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` on Android+Firefox.

Also, I've found that it only seems to affect `FLOAT` textures. If I change the type to `UNSIGNED_BYTE`, it passes.

Because I'm not familiar with opengl in general, it's likely that I've made some obvious oversight (e.g. not binding a required property) and mobile firefox is the only browser that didn't silently fix my mistake.

Another possibly relevant thing is having to pass `GL.FRAMEBUFFER` into `gl.checkFramebufferStatus`, instead of the actual `frameBuffer` instance. When I pass `frameBuffer`, the result is just always 0. Normally 0 means success, but [the mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/checkFramebufferStatus) don't even list 0 as a possible return value for this function; they say the good result is `FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`.

Comment: You need to check if `gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');` returns non-null to see if that feature is supported.

Comment: [`checkFramebufferStatus`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml) does not have any overload accepting a framebuffer object as argument, it's supposed to be called *exclusively* with `gl.FRAMEBUFFER` and check the currently bound framebuffer. Have you checked if the `OES_texture_float` extension is actually supported?

Comment: @WacławJasper I removed that check from the repro because it was returning non-null on all the browsers I tested, including firefox+android. I put the check back in since it's causing confusion to omit it.

Comment: The mobile version of firefox does seem to be failing an awful lot of conformance tests at https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/webgl-conformance-tests.html . Maybe it's a bug in the browser?

Comment: The `OES_texture_float` extension [**does not guarantee**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_float/)(see last point in overview section) that you're able to *render* to floating point textures. That's why [WEBGL_color_buffer_float](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_color_buffer_float/) was ***supposed to be introduced***, however it's rarely implemented, the only way to make sure is to check the framebuffer status as you already do.

Comment: @CraigGidney its possible. Otherwise you can check out the spec: https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf under `4.4.5 Framebuffer Completeness`.

Comment: Or the WebGL spec: https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#6.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's working **on the exact same phone** in other browsers then I'd [file a bug with Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

In general though, the ability to attach a floating point texture to a framebuffer is not universally supported. In OpenGL ES 2.0 no formats whatsoever are guaranteed to work :(

In WebGL, only 3 formats are guaranteed to work. [From the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#6.6):

> The following combinations of framebuffer object attachments, when all of the attachments are framebuffer attachment complete, non-zero, and have the same width and height, must result in the framebuffer being framebuffer complete:
>
> - COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture
> - COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture + DEPTH_ATTACHMENT = DEPTH_COMPONENT16 renderbuffer
> - COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture + DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT = DEPTH_STENCIL renderbuffer

All other combinations of attachments are up to the GPU/driver/browser.

Comment: How do people do multi-step GPU computations involving floats if they're only allowed bytes? Do they just keep manually packing and unpacking them between steps?

Comment: It does work in Chrome on the exact same phone, so I'll file a bug.

Comment: They either pack/unpack or else they only run on devices/browsers that support floats